# How can I edit my Vim configuration whilst working in Vim?

Tags: vimrc, set

I am new to Vim and I want to be able to edit scripts with my keyboard bindings and other Vim settings while still working in Vim.

For instance I would like all most of my `set xx` commands to be in one file and have the ability to update the file and reapply its settings while still in Vim. Is it a matter of `source`-ing the file as I am editing it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it a matter of `source`-ing the file as I am editing it?

Yes! `:so %` should do the trick when you're editing your `vimrc`. Or you can also use the special variable `$MYVIMRC` to access it from anywhere. I have a mapping like the following:

```
nnoremap <F5> :source $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

Caveats:

There are a few things you need to do to your `vimrc` to make sure you can re-`source` it safely.

- Make sure all your functions start with `function!`. The `!` makes a re-declaration of the function simply overwrite the function without a warning.
- If you have any `autocmd`s, make sure you include them in a group and start the group with `au!`. This will make sure that you don't set up your `autocmd`s more than once. And if you edit one, it will delete the old instance.

Example:

```
augroup MyAutocmds
   au!
   autocmd...
   autocmd...
augroup END
```

Comment: `map <F9> :so $MYVIMRC<Enter>:echo ".vimrc reloaded"<Enter>` is mine, but roughly the same thing :)